# ¿Cómo hago para que mi frame muestre los datos del jLabel sin tener que redimensionar la ventana?

Tags: java, java-swing

Esta es la función de la ventana, el problema es que al correrlo, me muestra el frame sin datos y debo redimensionar la ventana para ver los cambios, sé que hay un método para ello, pero no recuerdo cual es y estuve investigando en la documentación y no la encontré.
  No es necesario entender el código solo necesito el nombre de la función.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

class Party {
  private JFrame window = new JFrame();
  private JLabel fond = new JLabel();
  private JLabel header = new JLabel("Party at Tim's");
  private JButton bet = new JButton("You bet");
  private JButton shoot = new JButton("Shoot me");
  private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  private Container contentPane = window.getContentPane();

  public void buildInvite() {
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    window.setBounds(250, 50, 400, 400);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.pack();

    panel.setLayout(null);

    fond.setSize(400, 400);
    fond.setIcon(new ImageIcon("birthday.jpg"));

    header.setBounds(120, 150, 200, 50);
    header.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    header.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30));

    shoot.setBounds(60, 300, 100, 25);

    bet.setBounds(220, 300, 100, 25);

    window.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.add(bet);
    panel.add(shoot);
    panel.add(header);
    panel.add(fond);
  }
}
```

Comment: bet, shoot y fond son los labels, con los tres tengo el mismo problema

Comment: puedes poner el código completo?

Comment: No es necesario no es un problema de lógica, simplemente hay una función que lo soluciona, pero no recuerdo cual era y no la encontré en la documentación oficial

Answer (score 0):

panel.updateUI()

Resets the UI property with a value from the current look and feel.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html